# How do i convert 2014-12-19T05:00:00 to proper datatime, 2014-12 in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I get a date in data which looks like this "2014-12-19T05:00:00". I want to convert it in order to obtain a Date or String object and get something like "01-04-2018" that its "dd-MM-YYYY" in dataframe. How can I do it?
The result will be used for time series. So far,my time series result is like this, perhaps because it doesn't detect the date format (x-axis not in datetime).

[image]

Date column:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## For a pandas dataframe column/series:

Convert a string column (dtype of *object*) to a datetime column (dtype of *datetime64[ns]*) using [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). Then if you want another column with your datetimes back in a string format of your choosing, use [dt.strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).

An example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "Date": ["2014-12-19T05:00:00", "2014-12-20T05:00:00", "2014-12-21T05:00:00"],
  "Value": [0, 2, 4]})
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['MyDateTimeString'] = df['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(df)
#                   Date  Value            DateTime MyDateTimeString
# 0  2014-12-19T05:00:00      0 2014-12-19 05:00:00       2014-12-19
# 1  2014-12-20T05:00:00      2 2014-12-20 05:00:00       2014-12-20
# 2  2014-12-21T05:00:00      4 2014-12-21 05:00:00       2014-12-21
```

## In general:

To read your strings into datetime objects, use [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime.strptime("2014-12-19T05:00:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

Then to get a string representation of those datetime objects, use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
d.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

For more general string-to-datetime parsing, the [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library is handy:

```
import dateparser

dateparser.parse("2014-12-19T05:00:00").strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
# '19-12-2014'
dateparser.parse("December 19, 2014 at 5am").strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
# '19-12-2014'
```

Comment: Do you know how to change the column in dataframe, instead of string? Column as in edited question

Comment: @swm Edited my response to add an answer for pandas Series.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/
(Install with `pip install python-dateutil`.)

```py
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> d = dateutil.parser.isoparse('2014-12-19T05:00:00')
>>> print(d.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
12-19-2014
```

Comment: you might mention, that dateutil is not a standard module, but that it has to be installed with `pip install python-dateutil`